# Помогите разобрать пример с bind

Tags: javascript, bind

```js
var theSet = ["Carel Haverbeke", "Maria van Brussel",
              "Donald Duck"];
function isInSet(set, person) {
  return set.indexOf(person.name) > -1;
}
 
console.log(ancestry.filter(function(person) {
  return isInSet(theSet, person);
}));
 
 
console.log(ancestry.filter(isInSet.bind(null, theSet)));
```

Первый console.log понятен. А второй который с bind... я сначала не понял почему никуда не передается person, он ведь по идее будет undefined. Ведь filter принимает функцию, аргумент которой равен каждому отдельно взятому элементу перебираемого массива. А тут просто theSet.

Я правильно понимаю, что при такой записи возвращается функция, но в ней уже заранее прописан первый аргумент theSet? То есть получается обычный фильтр filter(function (person){return set.indexOf(person.name) > -1;}), а аргумент set как бы в памяти, если так можно выразиться? Просто хочу убедиться, что понял как работает второй вариант вызова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, Вы понимаете правильно.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```
fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

> **arg1, arg2, ...** - Arguments to prepend to arguments provided to the
>   bound function when invoking the target function.
>
> **arg1, arg2, ...** - параметры, которые будут переданы в функцию `fun`, перед теми, которые
>   будут переданы в функцию, возвращаемую `fun.bind`, кодом, который будет
>   эту функцию вызывать